# sound optimization for web/online

Tags: mastering

hi, i've been wondering about this issue (sound optimization for web/online) for some time now... i completed sound design for two short films. the design work was mainly about creating space and overall atmospheric tone. both soundtracks consist mostly of soft ambience sounds, room tones, delicate drones, mild nature sounds, etc. the mix sounds very well when played through standard monitors / loudspeakers, however the entire soundtrack disappears almost utterly when played via average laptop speakers. i'd like to add selected parts of the movies to my online portfolio. therefore, i want to find a strategy to track those elements (or frequency bands) that are currently not audible and try boost them a bit or improve their resolution, with the aim of bringing the soundtrack to sound reasonable on laptop speakers as well. how would you recommend going about doing that? ... so far i've played around with the Waves MaxxBass plugin an used it to enhance some of the low end that looses much of its presence when played via laptop speakers... yet i reckon there's a lot more work to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/remixing-for-the-internet). There are some very useful tips for Internet mastering. It might help you.